# Loading a form via AJAX with drupal_get_form()

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am trying to load a form via ajax, here is the code i use:

JS:

```
bigPopupBut.click(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://site/group_create",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                bigPopup.append(data);
            }
        });
})
```

The group_create is a PHP script that returns me a form, here is the code i used:

```
$node_type = 'group';
    $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';     
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->name = $user->name ;
    $node->field_city['und']['0']['value'] = $user->field_city['und']['0']['value'];
    $node->field_country['und']['0']['value'] = $user->field_country['und']['0']['value'];
    $node->type = $node_type;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->path = '';
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $return=drupal_get_form($form_id,$node);
return $return;
```

The Problem i have is that the PHP callback doesn't just return me the form, but a whole page, with headers, body, so when i append it with JS i get a duplicate of the whole page in my bigPopup DIV.

What am i doing wrong ? how could i just get the form without the surounding page?

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just to do `echo render($return); exit();`.

Otherwise, you should change de delivery callback from the path of your page, and I'm pretty sure that exists one one Drupal for Ajax.

Comment: Thanks yvan, that worked though i had to echo a render array so i added: echo render($return);

Comment: Now that you have the rendered form, does submitting it work for you? How do you submit the form when it's created via AJAX?

Comment: Submitting should work fine. You're $_POST'ing the data back to the server, including the form id and form build id, so Drupal should process the form just fine and place you right back at the URL you were at.

Comment: You should use drupal_exit() instead