# Drupal Create Form with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to create a Drupal form on the fly with javascript? I know I can create a form, but how could I create all the Drupal hidden fields and other required pieces?

Or if this is even possible?

Comment: Possible, yes (though messy) but what problem are you trying to solve that loading in a form via AJAX wouldn't?

Comment: How can I load the form via Ajax?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/loading-a-form-via-ajax-with-drupal-get-form

Comment: @Clive while that question covers outputting the HTML for the form, there seems a lot of functionality missing. I'm [trying to do this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117959/how-to-load-a-form-via-ajax) and I get the form, but not the behaviors, e.g. the autocomplete tag field is not autocompleting.

Comment: @artfulrobot Just call `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` after the AJAX call - problem solved

Comment: I already have that - see the [code](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117959/how-to-load-a-form-via-ajax) - but it's not working